# Calculating the top margin

Tags: margins

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[showframe, paperwidth=40pc, paperheight=40pc, margin=4pc]{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{\thepage}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [block]
    {\Huge}
    {\thechapter\quad}
    {0pt}
    {}
    \assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{40pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\kant[1-4]
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]
[image]

How do calculate whatever I need to calculate so that the vertical space between the top of the page and the main body text is the same in both the first page of the chapter and the following page?

Comment: Just checking. You want "As any dedicated reader..." and "As is shown in the writings..." to be at the same vertical position the pages?

Comment: Yes, that was my intention.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, rather some hints towards one which are too long for a comment.

You want the general textblock to be the height of the text following the chapter title. You will also need a large topmargin to get the main text with lots of space above. You can set these for your document via the `geometry` package.

You will need to change the position of the chapter title so that it fits into the top margin, taking up no space in the textblock.

Being a GOM and not liking the result you want to achieve, that's it from me. Good luck.